# Loading tasks through parent folder

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want Gulp to load and run a task that is in a different folder.

For example:

files tree:

- root

  - lib

    - task.js
  - proj

    - gulpfile.js

`task.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('myTask', function() {
    console.log('done!');
});
```

and `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', ['myTask']);
```

What I've tried so far:

- `require('../lib/task.js')`
- `require('require-dir')('../lib/')`

In both cases I can see task.js **is** loaded, but I get the following error:

```
Task 'myTask' is not in your gulpfile
```

When `task.js` is in the `proj` folder or in a sub folder of it - it works fine,
so I think it has something to do about going up to the parent folder through "../" .

Why is this happening and what can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NodeJS's global or module.exports for this purpose.

http://www.hacksparrow.com/global-variables-in-node-js.html